# Show that $f$ has a simple pole at $0, -1, -2, \ldots$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity

I am given the function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0, -1, -2, \ldots \}\to\mathbb{C}$ that is holomorphic on its domain, such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(z+1)=zf(z)$. I want to show that $0, -1, -2, \ldots$ are simple poles of $f$ and that the residues are given by $(-1)^n/n!$ at $z=-n$. Any hints? I am thinking of using a Laurent series around each integer and show that there is only one reciprocal term, but I don't know how to incorporate the given that $f(1)=1$. Any hints?

Comment: Can you show that $f(z) = \frac{{f(z + n + 1)}}{{z(z + 1) \cdots (z + n)}}$? (Hint: repeated use of $f(z+1)=zf(z)$) What does this give you for $\lim _{z \to  - n} (z + n)f(z)$?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just found that out as I was working on it. Thank you! I also see how the residue result holds.